Creating Elasticsearch Indexes from JSON with Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch in .NET
I'm currently updating my NEST client, which is deprecated, to the latest Elasticsearch client, Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch. Previously, with NEST, I utilized the low-level client to create indexes from a JSON file containing mappings and settings, like so:
var response = await this.client.LowLevel.Indices.CreateAsync<BytesResponse>(formattedIndexName, bytes, ctx: cancellationToken);

However, this functionality is not available in the latest client. What would be the recommended approach for achieving a similar outcome with the latest client?
